# SQL Syntax in Mysql for vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO USER
            (fname,
             mname,
             lname,
             uname,
             password,
             status,
             address,
             gender,
             bdaym,
             bdayd,
             bdayy,
             age,
             contact,
             isactive,
             iscancelled)
VALUES      ('" & SafeSTR(TextBox1.Text) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(TextBox2.Text) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(TextBox3.Text) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(TextBox7.Text) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(MD5(TextBox9.Text)) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(Combobox2.text) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(TextBox4.Text) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(ComboBox1.Text) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(ComboBox3.Text) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(ComboBox4.Text) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(ComboBox5.Text) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(TextBox5.Text) & "',
             '" & SafeSTR(TextBox6.Text) & "',
             1,
             0)
```

what is the problem in my query?

Comment: God bless syntax highlighting, check the third word and you'll know the error.

Comment: @hims056, if you look at the blue words (which are reserved keywords in SQL/~MySQL) you'll notice `USER`, it can't be used as a table name without surrounding it with `\`` so it should be `INSERT INTO \`USER\``. **Edit:** Nice deleting your comment while I'm spending time answering the question in it.

Comment: @Adnan Oh sorry for that. I got it before you comment.

Comment: in vb.net i dont have any errors but i check my query in the query database i got an error in sql syntax error

Comment: How can I solve this can anyone help me...thanks...

Comment: @user1608485 How can you write value as `'" & SafeSTR(TextBox6.Text) & "'` in database. You need to write direct value instead of `textbox.text`.

Comment: @hims056 i just put in my module function safestr....SafeSTR = Replace(s, "'", "''").... that my code, that code is adapted to my another projct but the connection is ms access...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you comment

> in vb.net i dont have any errors but i check my query in the query
>   database i got an error in sql syntax error

You are getting this error when you are executing it in database query editor because you are putting dynamic value instead of static value. If you want to execute this in database query editor put static value. For example :

```
INSERT INTO USER
            (fname,
             mname,
             lname,
             .
             .
             .
             isactive,
             iscancelled)
VALUES      ('ABC',
             'XYZ',
             'PQR',
             .
             .
             .
             1,
             0)
```

Comment: ok got it...but when im running the program in vb.net... there's no problem or errors in vb but it does not add into my database

Comment: ok got it...but when im running the program in vb.net... there's no problem or errors in vb but it does not add into my database